# errors in java - finding maximum values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

Following is the program I wrote as an answer for the question -

"Now use ArrayList and the Integer wrapper class to store the values and initialize the elements by reading input from console using Scanner class.Extend the program to identify the n maximum values in the ArrayList."

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class ArraylistInput {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of you Array List ");
    int nos = in.nextInt();
    // Recorrd the input numbers
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nos; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter values for the ArrayList ");
        int Input = in.nextInt();
        val.add(Input);
    }

    // Display the arraylist
    for (int j = 0; j < nos; j++)
    {
        int x = val.get(j);
        System.out.println("Index " + (j+1) + ": " +  x);
    }
    System.out.println("How meny maximmum values do you want? ");
    int max =0; // initial max value
    int nmax = in.nextInt(); // number of maximum values
    int length = val.size(); // size of the arraylist

    // finding the maximum values in ascending order without sorting
    for (int h = 1; h <= nmax ; h++)
    {           
        for (int k=0;k < length; k++)
        {
            if (val.get (k) > max)
            {
                 max = val.get(k);
            }               
        }
        System.out.println ("maximmum = " + max);
        int z = val.indexOf(max); // removing the higest value after printing
        val.remove(z);
    }           
    }
}
```

> Output and Error:
>
> Enter the length of you Array List
>
> 3
>
> Enter values for the ArrayList
>
> 12
>
> Enter values for the ArrayList
>
> 45
>
> Enter values for the ArrayList
>
> 8
>
> Index 1: 12 Index 2: 45 Index 3: 8
>
> How meny maximmum values do you want?
>
> 2
>
> maximmum = 45
>
> Exception in thread "main" maximmum = 45
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)     at
>   ArraylistInput.main(ArraylistInput.java:46)

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

```
Collections.sort(myList, Collections.reverseOrder());
List<Integer> maxn = myList.subList(0, n);
System.out.printf("The maximum %d values are: %s%n", n, maxn);
maxn.clear(); //This clears the sublist and removes its elements from the source list
```

That would give you a list with the maximun n elements in your list.

Comment: I would prefer this too. But keep in mind that `subList()` returns a view. Any changes to `myList` will reflect in `maxn`.

Comment: @nansen Then add the sublist to another list: `List<Integer> maxn=new ArrayList<>(myInts.subList(0,n))`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have a single ArrayList you don't need the nested for loop to find the maximum:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   current = list.get(i);
   if(current > max)
      max = current;
}
```

The nested for loop when you are searching for the maximum tries to access a value in your list that doesn't exist, which is why you are receiving this error.

Comment: I believe the question is about getting the `n` maximun elements, not just one.

Comment: pretty simple to adjust this to get the n max

Answer (score 0):

Your `max` is never getting assigned and then you are trying to remove a non-existing element from the arraylist. Set `max` to some value that cannot occur in the list and then check whether it ever got assigned in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element from the list with:

`val.remove(z);`

You change the size of the list but you don't update your `length` variable. This causes you to try to access indices beyond the size of the array, resulting in a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, consider saving both the *index of the max value* and the *max value itself*. Then, when you go to remove the value, you can use `ArrayList.remove()` directly without searching the whole list again for the max index (which is what `ArrayList.indexOf()` will do).